# Basic Google Sign-In for Websites code not working in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-oauth, google-openid, google-signin

I am attempting to use Google Sign-In for Websites (https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/) and noticed that my solution is not working in Internet Explorer 11. To try to eliminate as many factors as possible, I created a simple test case based on the sample code provided by Google.

I've tested it in Chrome on my Windows 7 PC, Chrome on my Mac, Safari on my Mac, Firefox on my Mac and Safari on my iPhone. It works on all of these (e.g., when I click the sign in button and select/enter my Google account, it returns to the page and the button says, "Signed in").

It does not, however, work on Internet Explorer 11 on PC or, strangely enough, Chrome for iOS. When the button is clicked, a window opens to allow me to select my Google account, but after making a selection, the window closes and returns to the page with a button that still says, "Sign In."

Here is the sample code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="61023618497-vqfbod57f26ncjl9d6firk3t09ve4tt3.apps.googleusercontent.com">
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="g-signin2"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas as to what might be going on? I've searched around and have not found any solutions.

One idea was to add "accounts.google.com" to IE's Trusted Sites. This didn't work. I also tried accessing the page via https instead of http. That didn't make a difference either. Anything else I should try?

Comment: We need Google to fix this. Anyone know a way to open an issue with them? I updated the tags on this question and another (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31494204/google-sign-in-for-web-apps-not-working-with-internet-explorer) to both of the ones they recommend (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-federated-login-api/TL9Pxn_s7yw)

Comment: This has been resolved in a recent update to Google Sign-in (Nov. 19,2015). The pages you referenced should now work in IE11/Edge.

Comment: It appears this defect was fixed sometime around November 23rd 2015 https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-javascript/issues/12 As this is a commentary page it is hard to represent it here in this post. Have a read.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was a bug on Google's end that is now fixed.

Comment: I still have this problem in IE 11 while using HTTP protocol (other browsers works fine)

Comment: There's more information on that github link now. 
"Note that sign-in on localhost does not work due to localhost cookie behavior. " 
They also provide an example at http://gusclass.com/demos/button2/min.html.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem now, a few months later.

If you look at:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button

and try a signin with their demo button, it does not work with IE11 (but it works with other browsers I am using at different OS). I could not find any solution.

I am leaving the comment for a future reader, who searches for the same problem in the future. If the demo button at Google does not work, she can at least rest assured that the problem is probably not in her code. :)

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that you don't have IE 11 configured to block all third party cookies.

Third party cookies are required, and the user experience that occurs when third party cookies are blocked--as you've discovered--leaves much to be desired. There is no warning or error message presented to the user.

You could try to catch the error before it happens. It is possible to detect whether or not third party cookies are blocked by trying to set a cookie on a second domain (that you control) and then making a second request to ensure the cookie is set. You'll need a script or something on your server that can set and check for the cookie (it can't be done using only JavaScript because of the browser security model).

Comment: This isn't the issue, at least the one I'm seeing.  I get the 'SCRIPT5: Access is Denied' error in the IE console, and it refers to a Google iframe. Changing IE to allow all cookies (Low security settings) has no effect. Adding the serving site, accounts.google.com, etc. to trusted sites has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

I've had success doing the following:
Loading the script to initiate the Google button rendering etc. from $document.ready. (i.e.Whatever you have in the apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js?onload= x )

e.g.

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js?onload=startApp" async defer></script>
```

Move startApp() to here:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    startApp();
```

Where startApp() looks something like this:

```
function startApp() {
    gapi.load('auth2', function () {
        gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1').then(function () {
            gapi.signin2.render('signin-button', {
                scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login',
                fetch_basic_profile: false
            });
            gapi.auth2.init({
                fetch_basic_profile: false,
                scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'
            }).then(
                function () {
                    console.log('init');
                    auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
                    auth2.isSignedIn.listen(updateSignIn);
                    auth2.then(updateSignIn());
                });
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I struggled to get the example to work on localhost, but as soon as I deployed it to the real URL, it worked.