# Google Sign-in in Internet Explorer / Edge

Tags: javascript, google-signin

I am attempting to get a hello world google sign-in going. The code below has worked in Chrome and Firefox, but fails to work in Edge or IE 11. It is [the most basic example](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button) from the official google site.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="533332380921-7m8eoi4968kvl1mmr0kk3clco25loemg.apps.googleusercontent.com">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="my-signin2"></div>
  <script>
    function onSuccess(googleUser) {
      console.log('Logged in as: ' + googleUser.getBasicProfile().getName());
    }
    function onFailure(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
    function renderButton() {
      gapi.signin2.render('my-signin2', {
        'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login',
        'width': 200,
        'height': 50,
        'longtitle': true,
        'theme': 'dark',
        'onsuccess': onSuccess,
        'onfailure': onFailure
      });
    }
  </script>

  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=renderButton" async defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The button is rendered correctly, and when I click on it a new page loads. However, this page (which should show the sign-in stuff) is blank, and is quickly closed. None of the success or failure callbacks are triggered.

Comment: anything in the console log?

Comment: Nothing out of the ordinary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31170572/basic-google-sign-in-for-websites-code-not-working-in-internet-explorer-11?rq=1 (also unanswered at this time)