# Google auth issue on the internet explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-oauth, google-authentication, google-openid

I want to use Google auth on my website and everything is fine on chrome. But when i try to login on the Internet explorer, the popup browser window is open and I have the next error:

> SCRIPT5: Access denied.

My js google auth code:

```
auth2.grantOfflineAccess({
    'redirect_uri': 'postmessage'
  }).then(function(authResult) {
    console.log(authResult);
    });
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31494204/google-sign-in-for-web-apps-not-working-with-internet-explorer and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31170572/basic-google-sign-in-for-websites-code-not-working-in-internet-explorer-11 we are still waiting for google to fix and/or respond

Comment: Note: it works on IE10, but not IE11 nor Edge